# How to use notification in Firebase functions? Error: could not handle the request

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-notifications

I can't use notification from function request of firebase, what's wrong? 
Error: could not handle the request

Thanks

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7JUj.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
var message = {
  notification: {
    title: '$GOOG up 1.43% on the day',
    body: '$GOOG gained 11.80 points to close at 835.67, up 1.43% on the day.'
  }
};

admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token,message)
```